How to configure a linter (e.g. Ruff) to disallow double assignments in single lines in Python?
I'm looking for a way to configure a linter (such as Ruff or another popular Python linter) to disallow double assignments in single lines, like this:
name, position = files.name, pos

Instead, I want the linter to enforce separate assignments on separate lines, like this:
name = files.name
position = pos

However, I still want to allow tuple unpacking, like this:
name, position = extract_details()

Is there a way to configure a linter to achieve this behavior? If so, how can I do it?

I doubt there's a way to do this, because I doubt there are many people who want such a style rule. Code like x, y = y, x to swap two variables is considered an essential idiom. If name, position = files.name, pos feels wrong, maybe that has more to do with files.name and pos seeming like unrelated sources of information when there isn't a name like extract_details present to make the relationship explicit. Perhaps you actually want a tool that suggests refactorings, rather than a linter?
